# My Command Prompt is disabled. How can I re-enable it?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

Whenever I open a Command Prompt I get the following message:

> The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator.

I am the administrator so I have full rights; it was always like that.

I really need to use the Command Prompt to install PHP and Apache on my computer, as well as prehacking Flash games.

How can I get access to the Command Prompt?

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: Are you on a domain? It is possible that the domain admins have disabled the cmd prompt using GPO

Comment: @Alex Windows xp version.

Comment: @JoeTaylor When I bought the computer, the cmd was disabled.

Comment: @aristos007, to regain ownership of this question you need to register you accounts on SO and SU with the same credentials, once the accounts are linked you'll automatically own this question again.

Answer (score 1):

Either edit the registry directly (**Note:** the usual disclaimers about hacking your registry by hand apply) In regedit, navigate to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System, open the DisableCMD entry and set thevalue to 0

Or use XP Professional's Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc). Go to User Configuration|Administrative Templates|System and open the "Prevent access to the command prompt" entry. From here you can either disable the policy or set it to Not Configured.