# Re-enable command prompt in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I tried to run Windows 7 on a workstation and I don't want the users to use command prompt. So I followed one guide, with group policy, [Disable Command Prompt Using Group Policy or Registry Trick](https://www.top-password.com/blog/disable-command-prompt-using-group-policy-or-registry-trick/).

But now I can not use command prompt any more.

> This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.

But I am the administrator. In fact, it is the only account on the workstation now. I haven't created any users.

I can not use `gpedit` or `regedit` for the reason above. So the answer here, [My Command Prompt is disabled. How can I re-enable it?](https://superuser.com/questions/337017/my-command-prompt-is-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-it) seems invalid to me.

How can I regain access to command prompt and how should I do the command prompt ban correctly for certain groups of users? I can't see any option to apply the policy on any group.

Comment: You really shouldn't just run random commands off the internet withou backups. That site seems *really* dodgy. Can you fire up regedit from the run window (when you hit win r) with the full path?

Comment: No I can't do that either. C:\Windows\System32\regedt32.exe (OR C:\Windows\System32\gpedit.msc) returns the same error.

Comment: is powershell also disabled by this?

Comment: Congratulations. You won a "Reinstall windows" event. Feel free to execute at your earliest convenience.

Comment: So probably you need to rephrase your question to "How do I enable regedit" :)

Comment: Can't you run regedit from the run command interface `Win-R`? Opening a Command Prompt window is not the only way to run commands.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, try enabling  registry by adding this key:

`REG add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v DisableRegistryTools /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

Press Windows key + R and paste the key. Restart PC and try accessing regedit.